# Multicolored line plot inside of a matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently using a matplotlib figure with subplots to plot some curvature count histograms and the contour these belong to.

I wish to plot these contours as multicolored lines with the local curvature as color condition.

The code I have now is:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.tight_layout()
gs1 = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=2, ncols=3)

fig_ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0, 0])
fig_ax1.title.set_text('timestep = 0')
fig_ax1.hist(curvature0, weights=np.ones(len(curvature0)) / len(curvature0), bins=20)

fig_ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0, 1])
fig_ax2.title.set_text('timestep = 40')
fig_ax2.hist(curvature10, weights=np.ones(len(curvature10)) / len(curvature10), bins=20)

fig_ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0, 2])
fig_ax3.title.set_text('timestep = 120')
fig_ax3.hist(curvature18, weights=np.ones(len(curvature18)) / len(curvature18), bins=20)

fig_ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[1, 0])
fig_ax4.plot(xcoordinates[0], ycoordinates[0])

fig_ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[1, 1])
fig_ax5.plot(xcoordinates[10], ycoordinates[10])

fig_ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[1, 2])
fig_ax6.plot(xcoordinates[18], ycoordinates[10])
plt.show()
```

Which outputs the following figure:

[image: 1]

I tried implementing the matplotlib example here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html

I am struggling with the fact that they create a new subplot and axs. I can't figure out how to do this in the grid I'm currently using for the subplots.

Any tips on how to make this plots would be appreciated!

Comment: The linked example draws on the subplot `axs[0]`, while you draw on `fig_ax4`. Just replacing `axs[0]` with `fig_ax4`  should be straightforward.

Comment: @JohanC I tried that but it does not draw any graph, just the empty subplot. Would I completely skip the `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True)` line? And what would I need to draw the colorbar on if fig is no longer created?

Comment: In your case, `fig` and `ax` come from `plt.figure()` and `fig.add_subplot(...)`, so you shouldn't use `plt.subplots()`. You still can use `fig.colorbar(..., ax=fig_ax4)`